# Android: Toolbar not showing

Tags: android, android-toolbar, kotlin

My App is written in Kotlin. I've removed the default Action bar:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    </style>

</resources>
```

Then I declared my own Toolbar in the activity:

```
class ResultActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var mToolbar: Toolbar? = null
    var realmRecyclerView: RealmRecyclerView? = null
    var flightAdapter: FlightRecyclerViewAdapter? = null
    var realmAccess: RealmAccess? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)
        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
        realmAccess = RealmAccess(baseContext)
        realmRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.realm_recycler_view) as RealmRecyclerView?

        // Set up the action bar.
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
        //supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
...
```

The XML is also added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.ResultActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Toolbar Title" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    ...
```

But still the Toolbar doesn't show up.

I've done this the same way in a previous app with good results, I can't see what the problem can be here.

Comment: What is the rest of your layout? Since you're using a `RelativeLayout`, it might be that the other children lie on top of the toolbar.

Comment: Like Firefox likes to say: Well... this is embarrassing! You are right. It was covered by the rest of the content. Thumbs up for you!

Comment: Great! Sometimes another pair of eyes is all that's needed ;-)

Comment: @nhaarman: you or the OP should add it as a proper answer, then.

Comment: @Cactus: I agree. nhaarman, would you add this as an answer, so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the toolbar height:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: It's not working. Even hardcoding it to 100dp doesn't work.